# ASP.Net c#, Repeater Itemcommand. I don't delete data

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

If Click button in repeater control, delete data in database but not working. I use Visiual Studio 2013. My project ASP.Net Website and I am useing MasterPage and My Database connectionstring command in web.config.

This is default.aspx.cs file

```
static string yol = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cs"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection baglanti = new SqlConnection();
SqlCommand sorgu = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader oku;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    baglanti = new SqlConnection(yol);
    sorgu.Connection = baglanti;
    baglanti.Open();
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        sorgu.CommandText = "select * from blog";
        oku = sorgu.ExecuteReader();
        haber.DataSource = oku;
        haber.DataBind();
        oku.Close();
    }
    baglanti.Close(); 
}

protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    baglanti.Open();

    if (e.CommandName == "sil")
    {
       int id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        sorgu.CommandText = "delete from blog where id=" + id;
        sorgu.ExecuteNonQuery();
        haber.DataBind();
    }
    baglanti.Close();
}
```

Default.aspx file

```
<form runat="server">
    <asp:Repeater ID="haber" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
         <ItemTemplate>
           <li class="mix nature" data-name="Woodstump">
       <a href="?<%# Eval("Id") %>"><img src="../img/work1.jpg" alt="" width="150px" height="150px"></a>
                 <h4> <%# Eval("baslik") %> <br />
                  <asp:Button ID="Button1"  Text="Button" runat="server" CommandName="sil" CommandArgument="<%# Eval("Id") %>" />
               </h4>
             </li>
           </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:Repeater>
    </form>
```

Edit: If i use this command `CommandArgument="<%# Eval("Id") %>"`, Exeption is "The server tag is not well formed"
     if i use this command `CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>'`, Not take exeption but not work(not delete data in database).

Comment: Is there any exception?

Comment: I used the try and cath command but not exeption. Page is re-load but data isn't delete

Comment: See you are giving command argument as 'sil' in html but using command name as 'sil' in code.
Use this
        
<asp:Button ID="Button1"  Text="Button" runat="server" CommandName="sil" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />

Comment: @Manu Sorry, i change it but i take this exeption:"The server tag is not well formed."

Comment: Try using single quotes in CommandArgument like this
CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>'
This should work.

Comment: Okey :) Worked @Manu Thank you

Comment: Post an "Up" to my comment if it helped. Thanx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are sending the parameters revers.

Change this:

```
CommandArgument="sil" CommandName='<%# Eval("Id") %>'
```

To this:

```
CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' CommandName="sil"
```